# Why is np reshape not working on np.matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have sparse matrix that I am trying to reshape:

```
_train_data = model.pipeline.transform(train_data)
print(type(_train_data), _train_data.shape)
>>> <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> (18864, 3742)
```

I first convert it to a dense numpy array:

```
 _train_data = _train_data.todense()
 print(type(_train_data), _train_data.shape)
 >>> <class 'numpy.matrix'> (18864, 3742)
```

Then attempt to reshape it, with the goal of it being shaped (18864, 3742, 1) so I can fit into some keras dense layers, but the reshaping does not appear to be working:

```
a_new_df = _train_data.reshape((18864, 3742, -1))
print(type(a_new_df), a_new_df.shape)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrix'> (18864, 3742)
```

I have also tried using np.reshape():

```
a_new_df = np.reshape(_train_data, (18864, 3742, -1))
print(type(a_new_df), a_new_df.shape)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrix'> (18864, 3742)
```

and using a different axis to reshape:

```
a_new_df = np.reshape(_train_data, (18864, 3742, 1))
print(type(a_new_df), a_new_df.shape)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrix'> (18864, 3742)

a_new_df = np.reshape(_train_data, (1, 18864, 3742))
print(type(a_new_df), a_new_df.shape)
>>> <class 'numpy.matrix'> (18864, 3742)
```

But none of these are successfully recasting the shape of the matrix.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to add an extra array of shape **(18864, 3742)** along a 3rd axis? Like a stack of **18864 x 3742** arrays?

Comment: `np.matrix` class objects are always 2d.  Reshape does not change that.  `arr = _train_data.toarray()` makes a 2d array that can be reshaped to 3d.  `train_data.A` is short cut to do the same thing.  `csr` sparse is also 2d.

Answer (score 0):

From the matrix docstring:

> A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature
>   through operations.

If you want to reshape you need an array instead. matrix and sparse objects have the .A property that returns an array.